# Casting error with uploading files

Tags: c#, casting, httppostedfile, httpfilecollection

I was working on my website when i noticed my foreach loop wasn't working to upload a list of files and a for loop did work. I am curious to find out why the for loop works and the foreaches loop aren't.

The error message i got was: Cannot cast system.string to xx.

So these are the loops i have:

```
HttpFileCollection documentsList = Request.Files;

// Doesn't
foreach (var file in documentsList.Cast<HttpPostedFile>())
{
    var test = file;
}

// Doesn't
foreach (var file in documentsList)
{
    var test = (HttpPostedFile)file;
}

// Works
for (int i = 0; i < documentsList.Count; i++)
{
    var file = (HttpPostedFile) documentsList[i];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you look at [`HttpFileCollection`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it becomes clearer...

The [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eh0fcdh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a declared type of `HttpPostedFile`. Whereas [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> This enumerator returns the keys of the collection as strings.

So basically your `foreach` loop is iterating over the keys in the collection, whereas you want the values. This is inherently a weird design decision in [`NameObjectCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You could use:

```
foreach (var file in documentsList.Cast<string>()
                                  .Select(key => documentsList[key]))
{
    ...
}
```